# Equation with $ \sqrt[5]{}$

Tags: solution-verification

How to show that this equation $ \sqrt[5]{20-2x} + \sqrt[5]{7-x}+\sqrt[5]{3x+5}=2$ have 3 solutions 9, -6 and -25

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7B20-2x%7D%20%2B%20%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7B7-x%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7B3x%2B5%7D%3D2)says  the equation have no solutions !

Comment: Your input may be problematic. Principal root and Real valued root are two different things generally.

Comment: Also, usually when you input $\text{(x)^(1/5)}$ wolfram realises that you might want to say the real root instead of the principal value of the complex root, but, if you start inputing latex code, wolfram dedicates its resurces to interpreting what you're writing, rather than assessing alternative interpretations of your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sqrt[5]{20-2x}= a$  etc.,   $a+b+c=2$

$$a^5+b^5+c^5=32=(a+b+c)^5$$

Use [How to factor $(a +b+c) ^5 -(a^5+ b^5 + c^5)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596413/how-to-factor-a-bc-5-a5-b5-c5) to discover that $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=0$ should give three solutions.

Comment: Based on real-valued root, not principal.

Comment: @lonestudent, Please elaborate

Comment: Please do not view this as a negative comment..  I mean, if we take the principal root under the odd degree radical, then actually there is no real solution, right?

Comment: @lonestudent, No no, its fine. I just wanted to learn your point. Please feel free to comment for your query/doubt

Comment: Ah ok https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2820-2x%29%5E%281%2F5%29+%2B+%287-x%29%5E%281%2F5%29%2B%283x%2B5%29%5E%281%2F5%29%3D2&assumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22

Comment: Thank you @lab bhattacharjee

Comment: What should we do when we actually see such an equation?  For example, let's say a teacher gave homework.  My teacher, "what root use do you allow?"  Is it the real-valued root or is it the principal root?  What should we base on when solving the equation?  Or is that unimportant?  Should we calculate directly on real valued roots?Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The claim that $9,-6,-25$ are the solutions of the equation does not hold.

Substituting for example $x=9$ into the equation one obtains:
$$
(2)^\frac15+(-2)^\frac15+(2^5)^\frac15\ne2
$$
because
$$
(2)^\frac15+(-2)^\frac15\ne0
$$
for any pair of the fifth order roots of $2$ and $-2$ belonging to the same branch.

Comment: For me @user  $(-2)^\frac15=-2^\frac15$

Comment: The two roots reside in different branches of $z^{1/5}$.

Comment: I was taught that $ x \to x^{2n + 1} $ is a bijection $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, its reciprocal function is $ x \to x ^ {\frac 1 {2n + 1}} = \sqrt [2n + 1] {x} $ and $\forall x\in \mathbb R, \sqrt [2n + 1] {-x}=-\sqrt [2n + 1] {x}$  It's a shock for me to tell  otherwise

Comment: I believe that the real definition of the function is out-of-date and certainly is not used by default by WA: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7B-2%7D.

Comment: I take it by this discussion that such branches do not "mix and match" as it were?  Certainly the original equation does not show any particular limitations on the available branches...

Comment: In my opinion if an equation contains several instances of a multi-valued function, one should assume that  all the instances refer to the same branch of the function.